# Azure ARM - Baseline resources with ARM template

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-resource-manager, baseline

I have created an ARM template for deploying resources into an Azure Resource Group. Is there any way I could use the same ARM template to perform automated "Baseline-Checks" in order to check if the resources have been changed in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to determine if the state of the resources in Azure have "drifted" from the state declared in the template?  If so you can use the what-if api and parse the results from that to see if something has changed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell

If you want to prevent drift from occurring, you can lock the resources to prevent changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I knew about the -whatif flag however using that I couldn't save or do anything with the data. Using $results = Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult I can get the results I need. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

- You can perform baseline checks by using ARM template but you need to
  create individual template for each resource group in incremental
  mode  and when there is any changes in the resource it will
  automatically updated in the template and by that way you can perform
  baseline checks
- Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#resources) which helps in creating
  ARM template.